# Queue tasks with Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I recently started reading about coroutines and I want to ask about a certain scenario.

Consider a simple screen with one button. Upon clicking, it executes bunch of print statements and some delays (in between). I'm using coroutines to achieve this so far.

Now, my question is, if the user repeatedly spams this button, is there a way to queue up the task and execute it one by one (once the previous one is finished executing) on a dedicated thread?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val thread = newSingleThreadContext("thread")

        binding.button1.setOnClickListener {

            CoroutineScope(thread).launch {
               Log.d("ABC", " TEXT1 ")
               delay(1000)
               Log.d("ABC", " TEXT2 ")
               delay(2000)
            }

        }

}
```

Now, if I execute this, it runs fine and I can see the logs as such if I press the button once :

```
TEXT1
TEXT2
```

However, if I spam the button, this is what I see :

```
TEXT1
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT2
```

Basically, what is happening on my observation is, as the user is pressing the button, the couroutine is getting executed without any wait or check. So, my question is, how can I edit the code so that when the user spams the button, each courotine gets executed sequentially and each finishes before the next one begins to execute so that the output comes something like this:

```
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT1
TEXT2
```

Comment: `delay` is suspending function so it "frees up" the thread for another continuation to execute. Crude way to achieve what you want is replace `delay` with `Thread.sleep()` to keep the thread occupied, but ideally you should indeed implement some kind of queue.

Comment: Yes! You are right! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get that behavior with a Flow no matter what thread or threadpool you use:

```
class MyActivity : CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val myFlow = callbackFlow {
            binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
                offer(Unit)
            }
            awaitClose()
        }

        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            myFlow
                .collect {
                    Log.d("ABC", " TEXT1")
                    delay(1000)
                    Log.d("ABC", " TEXT2")
                    delay(2000)
                }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cancel()
    }
}
```