# How to run Kotlin coroutines sequentially?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have an instance of `CoroutineScope` and `log()` function which look like the following:

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

fun log(message: String) = scope.launch { // launching a coroutine
    println("$message")
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) // some blocking operation
}
```

And I use this test code to launch coroutines:

```
repeat(5) { item ->
    log("Log $item")
}
```

The `log()` function can be called from any place, in any `Thread`, but not from a coroutine.

After a couple of tests I can see not sequential result like the following:

```
Log 0
Log 2
Log 4
Log 1
Log 3
```

There can be different order of printed logs. If I understand correctly the execution of coroutines doesn't guarantee to be sequential. What it means is that a coroutine for `item 2` can be launched before the coroutine for `item 0`.

I want that coroutines were launched sequentially for each item and "some blocking operation" would execute sequentially, to always achieve next logs:

```
Log 0
Log 1
Log 2
Log 3
Log 4
```

Is there a way to make launching coroutines sequential? Or maybe there are other ways to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines sequential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480520/kotlin-coroutines-sequential-execution)

Comment: Thanks @TylerV. I wonder if there are alternative ways to accomplish this without using `Mutex`.

Comment: Look at the other answer too, using `join`. Could call `log("foo").join()`

Comment: @TylerV The other answer assumes to call `join` in a coroutine, it means I need  to call `log()` function in a coroutine, but this is not what I want. I want it to be called from any place without launching an outside coroutine.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way, you have to have log(2) wait until log(1) is done, and waiting must happen in a coroutine to keep from hanging, so the wait can either be inside log, with a lock, or outside log in a higher level coroutine.

Comment: If `log` is some function that should only ever have one instance running at a time and is launched from arbitrary places the lock is probably the easiest solution, unless you make a queue system where calling `log` queues some work and a separate work manager executes the work in order, but that would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: I also thought about creating the queue, It also seemed too complicated to me. I was thinking about channels, but they seem complicated as well.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254288/queue-tasks-with-coroutines), using a flow?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify in the question why the lock option doesn't work for you?

Comment: @TylerV I guess `Flow` may solve the problem, but I'm not sure how to use it here. I didn't write that lock option doesn't work for me, I just want some alternatives.

Comment: The channel option posted below might also be a good option - advantage of that over lock is that it also guarantees order, not just that a single one can run at once. It's basically the work queue concept.

Answer (score 5):

One possible strategy is to use a Channel to join the launched jobs in order. You need to launch the jobs lazily so they don't start until `join` is called on them. `trySend` always succeeds when the Channel has unlimited capacity. You need to use `trySend` so it can be called from outside a coroutine.

```
private val lazyJobChannel = Channel<Job>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED).apply {
    scope.launch {
        consumeEach { it.join() }
    }
}

fun log(message: String) {
    lazyJobChannel.trySend(
        scope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            println("$message")
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) // some blocking operation
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [`Flow`s are sequential](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows-are-sequential) we can use `MutableSharedFlow` to collect and handle data sequentially:

```
class Info {
    // make sure replay(in case some jobs were emitted before sharedFlow is being collected and could be lost)
    // and extraBufferCapacity are large enough to handle all the jobs. 
    // In case some jobs are lost try to increase either of the values.
    private val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>(replay = 10, extraBufferCapacity = 10)
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    init {
        sharedFlow.onEach { message ->
            println("$message")
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) // some blocking or suspend operation
        }.launchIn(scope)
    }

    fun log(message: String) {
        sharedFlow.tryEmit(message) 
    }
}

fun test() {

    val info = Info()

    repeat(10) { item ->
        info.log("Log $item")
    }
}
```

It always prints the logs in the correct order:

```
Log 0
Log 1
Log 2
...
Log 9
```

It works for all cases, but need to be sure there are enough elements set to `replay` and `extraBufferCapacity` parameters of `MutableSharedFlow` to handle all items.

---

Another approach is

Using `Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1)` as a context for the `CoroutineScope`. It makes coroutines run sequentially if they don't contain calls to `suspend` functions and launched from the same **Thread**, e.g. **Main Thread**. So this solution works only with blocking (not `suspend`) operation inside `launch` coroutine builder:

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1))

fun log(message: String) = scope.launch { // launching a coroutine from the same Thread, e.g. Main Thread
    println("$message")
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) // only blocking operation, not `suspend` operation
}
```

It turns out that the single thread dispatcher is a FIFO executor. So limiting the `CoroutineScope` execution to one thread solves the problem.