# Thread safe LiveData updates

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, race-condition

I have the following code which has a race condition. I try to find an item in a list and set its loading property. But if `onLoaded("A")` and `onLoaded("B")` are called multiple times from different threads. I always lose the data of the first call if it doesn't complete before second starts.

How can I make this work? Is using Mutex should be the correct approach?

```
val list = MutableLiveData<List<Model>>() // assume this is initialized with ["Model(false, "A"), Model(false, "B")]

data class Model(
    val loaded: Boolean,
    val item: String,
)

fun onLoaded(item: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val currList = list.value ?: return@launch

    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val updated = currList.find { it.item == item }?.copy(loaded = true)
        val mutable = currList.toMutableList()
        updated?.let {
            val index = mutable.indexOf(it)
            mutable[index] = it
        }
        list.postValue(mutable.toList())
    }
}

onLoaded("A")
onLoaded("B")

expected: ["Model(true, "A"), Model(true, "B")]
actual: ["Model(false, "A"), Model(true, "B")]
```

Comment: Why do you use a coroutine here? Do you invoke some `suspend` methods in it?

Comment: Maybe the example is not clear enough, my bad. I use coroutine here because I am actually changing the `Dispatcher`, when doing find and replace, since I don't want to have these operations running on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onLoaded()` a new coroutine is launched using `viewModelScope`. `viewModelScope` has `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` context, so the code inside it will be executed on the Main Thread, e.g. execution is limited to only one thread. The reason you have a Race Condition because calling the `onLoaded()` function consecutively doesn't guarantee the order of coroutines execution.

- If you call `onLoaded()` consecutively from one thread I suggest to remove launching a coroutine `viewModelScope.launch` in it. Then the order of calling will be preserved. Use `list.postValue()` in this case.
- If you call `onLoaded()` from different threads and still want to launch a coroutine you can refer to [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152449/how-to-run-kotlin-coroutines-sequentially).
- Try to use `@Synchronized` anotation without launching a coroutine:

  ```
  @Synchronized
  fun onLoaded(item: String) { ... }
  ```

  Method will be protected from concurrent execution by multiple threads by the monitor of the instance on which the method is defined. Use `list.postValue()` in this case.